# integrate Unity3D vth a native iOS application bt getting error shell script innovocation errorp

Tags: ios

i want to integrate Unity3D within a native iOS application bt getting error as a shell script innovocation error..please give me a solution for this as early as possible

Comment: What sort of integration are you talking about?  Which will be the main app, Unity's or yours?  How will you switch between them?

Comment: unity 3d integration within native ios applcations...actually in unity 3d it is directly opening the camera view first...bt  i have created one view before opening the camera...so when we click the button on the view..it has to go to unity 3d view..ie den it has to open the camera..bt it is not opening the camera view..it s getting error